# De-Serialize JSON List GUID objects containing child GUID objects

Tags: c#, json.net

The json string below  is list of 'Assignments' the top level Guid is the assignmentId.
Each assignment has a Guid identifier for the person and the item which is assigned to them.
I have tried a number of variants based on the JSON deserialisation answers currently on S.O.
My current attempt is

```
public class Assignments
{
     public Dictionary<Guid, Assignment> Documents { get; set; }
}
public class Assignment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Guid, AssignmentDetail> Assignments { get; set; }

}

public class AssignmentDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("personId")]
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("itemId")]
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON looks like

```
 {
  "abd9657b-8f5f-4320-a47a-9d8442003217": {
    "complete": null,
    "due": null,
    "estimate": null,
    "itemId": "f921a6d4-ee77-4655-9c97-1e29c29c8796",
    "personId": "c87b496f-0aba-4339-bb28-77d73283b504"
  },
  "353179f7-24ac-4331-ab86-41eabb8a9269": {
    "complete": null,
    "due": null,
    "estimate": null,
    "itemId": "d2a5de46-4100-47b8-8b8d-cad064c47fba",
    "personId": "9705d366-0d00-481b-a3f1-c8e596f4a7c7"
  },
  "d04b346b-e941-4985-92b1-45cc65925edf": {
    "complete": null,
    "due": null,
    "estimate": null,
    "itemId": "631e653e-7595-46cb-b01a-06fb1e66759a",
    "personId": "9705d366-0d00-481b-a3f1-c8e596f4a7c7"
  }
}
```

The current operation is

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Assignments>(result);
```

obj is null after the operation.

Ignore the missing leading bracket on the JSON string. Somehow I can't edit that section anymore.
thanks

Comment: Your JSON looks like a `Dictionary<GUID, SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` has five properties, three of them nullable (`complete`, `due` and `estimate`) and two more that are GUIDs (`itemId` and `personId`).  It could also be a dictionary where the values are Dictionaries (but I suspect that that's not what you want (since `complete` is unlikely a GUID).  You don't have three classes in there.

Comment: Thanks FlyDog57. You kicked back onto the right path. The answer was simply var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Guid, AssignmentDetail>>(result); How about putting it up as the answer so you get some points regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this.

First, I restructured your classes, coalescing them into a single `AssignmentDetail` class.  I set the types of the first three members to `string`.  They can be anything - as long as it's nullable.  I can't tell what type they should be, all your data makes them out to be `null`.

```
public class AssignmentDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("complete")]
    public string Complete { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("due")]
    public string Due { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("estimate")]
    public string Estimate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("itemId")]
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("personId")]
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    
}
```

Then I made your JSON more C# friendly (changing the inner quotes to single-quotes; they are equivalent):

```
private const string TheJson = @"
  {
    'abd9657b-8f5f-4320-a47a-9d8442003217': {
    'complete': null,
    'due': null,
    'estimate': null,
    'itemId': 'f921a6d4-ee77-4655-9c97-1e29c29c8796',
    'personId': 'c87b496f-0aba-4339-bb28-77d73283b504'
    },
    '353179f7-24ac-4331-ab86-41eabb8a9269': {
    'complete': null,
    'due': null,
    'estimate': null,
    'itemId': 'd2a5de46-4100-47b8-8b8d-cad064c47fba',
    'personId': '9705d366-0d00-481b-a3f1-c8e596f4a7c7'
    },
    'd04b346b-e941-4985-92b1-45cc65925edf': {
    'complete': null,
    'due': null,
    'estimate': null,
    'itemId': '631e653e-7595-46cb-b01a-06fb1e66759a',
    'personId': '9705d366-0d00-481b-a3f1-c8e596f4a7c7'
    }
}";
```

With that in place, this code works:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Guid, AssignmentDetail>>(TheJson);
```

The result is a dictionary with three entries, each keyed with a GUID, and each having appropriate `AssignmentDetail` data.

Comment: FYI-- although Json.Net tolerates single quotes as string delimiters in JSON, they are actually non-standard.  See [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/).  I would not recommend replacing standard delimiters with non-standard ones just for the sake of making the code more "friendly".

Comment: @BrianRogers: Good point, thanks.  It sure makes `const string`s easier to read in sample code though.  Most JSON I use in real code comes from outside the program.

Comment: @Flydog57 The crux is your working result statement. The <Dictionary<Guid,AssignmentDetail>> Once I understood the correct structure of Dictionary<Guid,Class> It all  came right. I have no control over the JSON string it is a service response with 26K entries. Thanks again for your help.